# Working with truncation of inverse of integers (number of necessary digits)

Tags: nt.number-theory, na.numerical-analysis, diophantine-approximation

Ideally I would like to find exact value of $Mr'$ where $r'=\frac{1}{M'}$ where $M'$ ranges from $1$ to $T+1$ and $1\leq M\leq T$ holds. However in real world approximations have finite precision. If I use truncation of $r'$ I get an estimate of $y\leq Mr'$. I just want to get a reasonable approximation of $r'$ such that if $y\leq1$ or $>1$ then $M\leq M'$ or $M'<M$ holds respectively.

The period of rationals can be as large as denominator. So in this case the number of digits should be at least $T$ in worst case since $M$ is upper bound by $T$. Is the lower bound $T$ on number of digits sufficient up to constant multiplicative factors or perhaps we may need $poly(T)$ number of digits or perhaps we need superpolynomial in $T$? What is the upper bound?

> Thus my question is following: How many digits in base $b$ should $r'$ be truncated to as a function of $T$ to ensure that $M<M'\leq T+1$ holds iff $0<y<1$ holds (that is it works even at $M'=M+1$ at every $M\in\{1,2,3\dots,T-1,T\}$)?

Comment: Well, of these, $1/(T + 1)$ is the closest to $0$ and $T/(T + 1)$ is the closest to $1$, so just however many digits you need to distinguish $1/(T + 1)$ from $0$ and $T/(T + 1)$ from $1$, right?

Comment: Yes the resolution is $\frac1{T+1}$ which gives an estimate of possibly at most $\frac{c\log T}{\log b}$ for the number of $b$ digits where $c$ is some constant with $c>0$.